# multiprocessing causes infinite loop of errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Using python 3.8 on osx Big Sur

The lines

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(2)
```

causes an infinite loop of errors, but a snippet of it is collected below.

Also, mp.freeze_support() does not seem to help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "/Users/biscuit/.conda/envs/advanced-projects/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 264, in run_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
.
.
.
```

Any ideas why?

Edit:

None of the solutions worked at the time, but it seems to be working today? I did install some other packages that made me do updates on dependencies so maybe it changed my multiprocessing version or some other package version that fixed it?

Either way its working now, sorry this won't be much help to others /:

Comment: Are you sure it's the creation of the pool and not the submission of a job with a call to a pool function such as `map` or `apply` that is causing the problem? Anyway, juding by the appearance of `spawn.py` in the stacktrace, it seems that your operating system uses a spawn call rather than a fork call to create new processes. So I must ask, is the pool-creation and job-submission logic enclosed in a **if \_\_name__ == '\_\_main__':** block?

Answer (score 3):

Specifically when the start method is "spawn" (default on MacOS now):

You must only ever create child processes (creating a pool creates child processes) inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block because the children import the `__main__` file. When that import happens the file gets executed (just like any import) and you will recursively keep creating more and more child processes unless some sort of thing (like the `if __name__ ...` block) limits execution to only the parent process.

Comment: It didn't work /: at least not in the console, even when it is inside a __name__ == '__main__'

Comment: @Travasaurus please show more of your code then... 2 lines isn't much to go on.

Comment: Hey Aaron, it seems to be working now, I'm not sure why. I made an edit to the post with a brief description of why it might be working now.